# Initializing a class in another class, but passing only set attributes

Tags: python, composition

I have a class, which is supposed to contain several other classes as its attributes - I believe *composition* would be the right term. Now, I want to initialize the attributes of the contained classes depending on whether they have been set in the containing class. In the following example, I would just override the defaults of the two minor classes with `None`, which I do not want:

```
class OneAttribute:
    def __init__(self,a=1):
        self.a = a

class TwoAttributes:
    def __init__(self,b=2,c=3):
        self.b = b
        self.c = 3

class SuperClass:
    def __init__(self,a=None,b=None,c=None):
        '''
        This would override the defaults in the
        other two classes, which is bad.
        '''
        self.one = OneAttribute(a=a)
        self.two = TwoAttributes(b=b,c=c)
```

I could alternatively define the containing class like below, but this is <s>not very nice nor extensible</s> simply horrible:

```
Class SuperClass:
    def __init__(self,a=None,b=None,c=None):
        if a is not None:
            self.one = OneAttribute(a=a)
        else:
            self.one = OneAttribute()

        if b is not None and c is not None:
            self.two = TwoAttributes(b=b, c=c)
        elif b is not None:
            self.two = TwoAttributes(b=b)
        elif c is not None:
            self.two = TwoAttributes(c=c)
        else:
            self.two = TwoAttributes()
```

Is what I am trying to achieve maybe a bad design decision?

Comment: Why are the default values in `SuperClass` different from those in the other classes?  Could you just make them the same?

Comment: Is ` def __init__(self,a=1,b=2,c=3):` an option? Then you can just call `OneAttribute(a)` and `TwoAttributes(b,c)` respectively.

Comment: One thing you don't mention is that you can move all the `if _ is not None` conditionals into the subclass `__init__` methods. That way you leave the `SuperClass` definition exactly like your first example and it just passes in `None`, which the subclass can handle, or a value, which the subclass should set.

Comment: Terminology note: `SuperClass` has *instances* of two other classes as its attributes, not the other classes themselves.

Comment: Are `OneAttibute` and `TwoAttribute` stand-alone classes, or designed specifically for use by `SuperClass`? Would it make sense for `SuperClass` to simply take an instance of each as arguments to `__init__`, rather than the values used to construct them? The right design depends on more information than you are giving.

Comment: @chepner: I like that idea a lot. I don't know why I didn't think of it. It's not the actual answer to my (badly phrased) question, but I believe this is exactly what I will use.

The other ideas are also very good. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to allow your class to accept extra keyword parameters

```
class OneAttribute:
    def __init__(self,a=1,**kwargs):
        self.a = a

class TwoAttributes:
    def __init__(self,b=2,c=3,**kwargs):
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
```

Then you can simply accept keyword parameters in the container class

```
class SuperClass:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.one = OneAttribute(**kwargs)
        self.two = TwoAttributes(**kwargs)
```

The downside is that if you pass an extra parameter to the two inner classes in other it would go undetected.

Avoiding this problem is possible, but requires some black magic: first you just declare the inner classes as usual:

```
class OneAttribute:
    def __init__(self,a=1):
        self.a = a

class TwoAttributes:
    def __init__(self,b=2,c=3):
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
```

then you discover using introspection what are the parameters they expect

```
def parms_of(f):
    return f.__code__.co_varnames[:f.__code__.co_argcount]
```

and pass only those to the inner classes constructor

```
def filter_kwargs(kwargs, f):
    s = set(parms_of(f))
    return dict((k, v) for k, v in kwargs.items()
                if k in s)

class SuperClass:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.one = OneAttribute(**filter_kwargs(kwargs, OneAttribute.__init__))
        self.two = TwoAttributes(**filter_kwargs(kwargs, TwoAttributes.__init__))
```

Comment: I was wondering: why do you write `f.__code__.co_varnames[:f.__code__.co_argcount]` instead of just `f.__code__.co_varnames`? Under which circumstances would your indexing by `f.__code__.co_argcount` return a different result than just printing all the var_names?

Comment: @mSSM: `co_varnames` is a tuple containing the names of all locals used in the function body, not just the parameters. The function parameters are always the initial part.